# Facebook Open Graph How to unlike the pages I like?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Okay, I have several thousands pages I've liked through the years and I CANNOT go to the edit likes pages and press TAB + DEL thousands of times to remove my likes by hand.

Isn't there a more automatic way to remove all the pages I liked through the years by using the open graph?

Makes you wish there was an Unlike All button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) documentation, under the [Likes connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes) there's nothing about changing/deleting or even adding likes, it just has a way of reading the user likes.

So as it looks, currently you have no way of automating this, and you'll have to manually go to each page you want to remove the like.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in the same way it is not possible to do an HTTP POST for a like; for a breach in security it can be used as an attack on a Facebook user.